# Executing terminal command from C program, doesn't behave as I would expect

Tags: c++, linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a variable that contains the WiFi signal strength. The following command return successfully when executed from the terminal

```
iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d"=" -f3 |cut -d" " -f1
```

Returns 74/100

But, when I put this into a system() call, I get the following compile error.

```
int main (){
system("iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d"=" -f3 |cut -d" " -f1");
return 0;
}
```

When I compile that...

$ c++ wifi.cc
wifi.cc: In function ‘int main()’:

wifi.cc:8:59: error: assignment of read-only location ‘"iwconfig $_[0]|grep Signal|cut -d"’

wifi.cc:8:59: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘const char [16]’ to ‘const char [34]’

Any ideas/suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: You may want to use `popen` to get the *output* of your command; you still will need to escape the command string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your string literal has unescaped quotation marks in it. You need to escape them:

```
system("iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d\"=\" -f3 |cut -d\" \" -f1");
```

In your incorrect code, the quotation marks are being paired up like this:

```
system("iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d"=" -f3 |cut -d" " -f1");
       ^                                   ^ ^            ^ ^    ^
       └─────────────────1─────────────────┘ └──────2─────┘ └─3──┘
```

As you can see, there are three separate string literals. After you escape the quotation marks, there is only a single pair of quotes as far as C++ is concerned:

```
system("iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d\"=\" -f3 |cut -d\" \" -f1");
       ^                                                             ^
       └──────────────────────────────1──────────────────────────────┘
```

The escaped quotes (those with `\` in front of them) are just part of the string.

However, in the terminal the command is not part of some string. It is just a command on its own and the quotations are paired up like so:

```
iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d"=" -f3 |cut -d" " -f1
                                   ^ ^            ^ ^
                                   └1┘            └2┘
```

Comment: That did it. I'm still scratching my head as to why that would work with on the terminal...may thanks!

Comment: @newtoxcode Because in the terminal it's not part of a string literal. The quotation marks don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `"` like so `\"`:

```
system("iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d\"=\" -f3 |cut -d\" \" -f1");
```

Otherwise what you have in the first case is:

```
"iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d" = " -f3 |cut -d"
                                     ^^^
```

which is trying to assign to a string literal, which is where the error `assignment of read-only location` is coming from.

Comment: That did it. I'm still scratching my head as to why that would work with on the terminal...may thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you're strings are simple enough and you want to avoid escape-hell, you could also use single-quotes in the shell-command, e.g.:

```
system("iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d'=' -f3 |cut -d' ' -f1");
```

this only works because in shell you can use both double-quotes and single-quotes for string literals (there *are* differences between the two, but let us not bother about them now).

apart from that i would suggest to use library calls rather than executing terminal programs. this should make your program faster (as you don't have to call an external program which calls a library to get some value and prints that; only for you to parse the printout and try to read the correct value), and more robust (e.g. if the output of `iwconfig` changes because of a new version or simply because it is running under a different language; or you are having multiple wireless connections, or...)

have a look at at [libiw](http://packages.debian.org/libiw-dev)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an escape sequence to add the quotation marks inside of the string like this:

```
system("iwconfig wlan0 |grep Signal| cut -d\"=\" -f3 |cut -d\" \" -f1");
//                                         ^^ ^^            ^^ ^^
```

Comment: That did it. I'm still scratching my head as to why that would work with on the terminal...may thanks!